# How to add Unitemporal document in MarkLogic

Tags: collections, marklogic, document, temporal

Can somebody give me a sample unitemporal document that we can use in MarkLogic? 
I need to create a collection on the system time and add some documents in it.
Also need to upload and check multiple versions of the same document. How to do these?

Answer (score 1):

Listing out all steps would be too much for a Stack Overflow answer. I recommend reading the [Temporal Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/temporal). It discusses both `uni-temporal` and `bi-temporal` in detail, and comes with fully explained examples.

Also worth reading is this blog about temporal support in MarkLogic, but mostly as introduction to the topic:

https://www.marklogic.com/blog/bitemporal/

HTH!

Comment: I've done that and added a document. However, when I try to search using the DateTime or timestamps it's returning only the latest version on the document and not the previous versions. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you open a new question, and spell out in more detail what you did and tried? You would normally search latest docs when search in the `latest` collection, but if you search across all, you should see all versions, provided you updated the same doc multiple times..